# Smart way to shorten the current working directory in pure Bash

Tags: performance, bash

I'm trying to create a shell prompt that displays the `$PWD` in a "smart" way. I want to display the top two directories rather than the full path. If `$HOME` is the parent (or parent of the parent) directory, I want to show it like `~`.

Assuming my `$HOME` is `"/home/user"`, here are a few test cases with expected output according to several `$PWD` values:

```
/                  -> /
/home              -> /home
/home/user         -> ~
/home/user/foo     -> ~/foo
/home/user/foo/bar -> foo/bar
/usr/local         -> /usr/local
/usr/local/games   -> local/games
/home/userr        -> /home/userr
```

Currently, my solution is as follow:

```bsh
path=$PWD

# $n is the number of "/" in the path indicating that there is more than 2 dirs
# In such case, the path should be truncated
# If the path contains root / (like "/home/usr"), 3 "/" implies 3 dirs 
# If the path is "~/foo" then only 2 "/" are required
# If ${PWD} starts with ${HOME}, we can replace this part with "~"
# A slash need to be appended to "${HOME}" to avoid false positive
n=3
if [[ ${path}/ == ${HOME}/* ]]; then
  path=~${path:${#HOME}}
  n=2
fi

# Count the number of "/" in the path
# If there is more than $n "/", this means the path contains more than 2 dirs
# In this situation, we need to extract the two last dirs only from the path
slashes=${path//[^\/]}
if [[ ${#slashes} -ge $n ]]; then
  dir=${path##*/}
  parentpath=${path%/*}
  parentdir=${parentpath##*/}
  path=$parentdir/$dir
fi

echo $path
```

This function is intended to be used in my bash shell prompt. As this will be issued each time I type a command in my terminal, and as I will keep this in my `.bashrc` for probably several years to come, I'm looking to "**optimize**" this function.

Could the solution have been implemented otherwise, or could this function be improved in some way in order to minimize it's overall "footprint"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning values by variable is 3-10 times faster than capturing an `echo` with `$( )`.  Your temp variable is already global.  Just name it something similar to what the surrounding function is named.

Whitespace and comments affect bash performance negatively.  It's not a big penalty, just something to be aware of.

A regular expression can do the "last two path components" extraction very compactly.

```
cwd() {
  cwd=$PWD
  [[ $cwd/ == $HOME/* ]] && cwd=~${cwd#$HOME}
  [[ $cwd =~ ./([^/]+/[^/]+)$ ]] && cwd=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=cwd

PS1="\$cwd \$"
```

I'd say not to count the tilde as a path component: it's only one extra character that carries a lot of information, well worth the single column.   The regex is then:

```
  [[ $cwd =~ (..|[^~])/([^/]+/[^/]+)$ ]] && cwd=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have figured out that best performances are reached by avoiding use of regex engine (and replacing `${HOME}/*` with index-based substring extraction).

Answer (score 1):

Based on @OhMyGoodness suggestions, here is an improved function:

```
cwd() {
    cwd=$PWD
    [[ $cwd/ == $HOME/* ]] && cwd=~${cwd:${#HOME}}
    begin=${cwd%?/*/*} && [[ "$begin" != "$cwd" ]] && path=${cwd:${#begin}+2}
}
```

It's slightly faster as it reduces string manipulations.